# function or instance declaration?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the next code

```
struct X
{
    X(float) {}
};

int const x = 3;

X f(float(x));
```

Should a standard C++ compiler parse the last line as a function declaration with type `X (*)(float)` or as making an instance of `X` by calling `X::X(float(3))` ?

Comment: That is a declaration

Comment: @Mahmoud Al-Qudsi - you're absolutely right. it is related

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a function declaration. Paragraph 8.2/1 of the C++11 Standard explains this:

> The ambiguity arising from the similarity between a function-style cast and a declaration mentioned in 6.8
>   can also occur in the context of a declaration. In that context, the choice is between a function declaration
>   with a redundant set of parentheses around a parameter name and an object declaration with a function-style
>   cast as the initializer. Just as for the ambiguities mentioned in 6.8, **the resolution is to consider any construct
>   that could possibly be a declaration a declaration**.

The Standard also provides an example:

```
struct S {
    S(int);
};
void foo(double a) {
S w(int(a)); // function declaration     <=== Your example
S x(int()); // function declaration
S y((int)a); // object declaration
S z = int(a); // object declaration
}
```

The declaration in your example declares a function that takes a `float` and returns an `X`, as proved by the (non-firing) static assertion in the following program ([**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e9f788ae97b887717300142ea51386d7-a63ad9fea3739cb794a74965e5d28fb3)):

```
#include <type_traits>

struct X
{
    X(float) {}
};

int const x = 3;

X f(float(x));

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(f), X(float)>::value, "!");
}
```

Comment: could you explain what type of function this declares, the example that is

Comment: @aaronman: I expanded the answer

Comment: so what happens to the `x` because `float(x)` is not a type right, in a function declaration you should have a type

Comment: @aaronman: `x` is considered as the name of the `float` argument of the function `f`. Writing `f(float(x))` is just an alternative way of writing `f(float x)` in a function declaration (I think this comes from C, but I'm not sure).